# Server Caching?

Tags: caching, server, upload

So, i have this issue where I've uploaded a web page and some supporting files (css, images, etc) - but when I make changes and upload the files, the changes don't show up.

I've tried clearing my local cache, deleting and re-uploading files, and even went into the server's cpanel (I have access to the WHM and backend) to do it directly through the file manager.  No changes are taking effect.

I went through and checked the source code to the css file and it's not the same as what I'm uploading.

Is there something I'm missing?  Is there such a thing as caching on the server? If so, how do I empty the cache, or fix the issue?

I'm kind of desperate.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using any CMS like WordPress or Joomla for your website? If yes, you need to check and disable any cache plugin installed.

Comment: I do have that on the same server - but I don't have any caching plugins installed.  I did, at one point, but that's not the case, now.

Comment: I should point out that this is on a dedicated server.

Comment: Did you try to delete all browser's cache (CTRL+SHIFT+DEL or completely close the browser and reopen it)? But anyway, you tell "I went through and checked the source code to the css file and **it's not the same as what I'm uploading.**" so I think there may be an upload problem. Try to modify the file directly from within the cpanel (e.g. by inserting deliberating wrong code to see if something changes)

Comment: I deleted all local/browser cache.  As for the uploading? I went directly though the sites file uploader in CPanel.  As well as an FTP program.  My question is this - we have certain security softwares in place on our server. Do you think that one of them might be caching?  If so, is there a quick work around?

Comment: without knowing your server infrastructure, it's hard to help you. Try to post some info like the server OS, version, application installed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK! As it stands - I have solved the problem.
The issue was [SiteLock](https://sitelock.com/) Security.  It caches a great deal of information that we don't want.  While on the phone with support, they ended up showing me how to get 1) purge the caching, and 2) change the settings for caching specific information.

I *DO* want to thank you all for your input.  I *DID* lead me down the right path.  Kudos to you!

Thanks, again!
-mb